# Errors installing apache-airflow wheel

Tags: python, airflow, flask-appbuilder

I am running a pyenv with python 3.8.12. I am installing a requirements.txt that contains apache-airflow 1.10.5 (old I know). I am getting the below error. I have attempted to upgrade setuptools, install apispec (and upgrade), and also upgrade pip (although its attached to my pyenv). Was hoping someone may have an idea of what to try next. Thanks

```
    pip3 install "apache-airflow==1.10.5"
Collecting apache-airflow==1.10.5
  Using cached apache_airflow-1.10.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.9 MB)
Collecting alembic<2.0,>=1.0 (from apache-airflow==1.10.5)
  Using cached alembic-1.10.3-py3-none-any.whl (212 kB)
Collecting cached-property~=1.5 (from apache-airflow==1.10.5)
  Using cached cached_property-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting colorlog==4.0.2 (from apache-airflow==1.10.5)
  Using cached colorlog-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting configparser<3.6.0,>=3.5.0 (from apache-airflow==1.10.5)
  Using cached configparser-3.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting croniter<0.4,>=0.3.17 (from apache-airflow==1.10.5)
  Using cached croniter-0.3.37-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting dill<0.3,>=0.2.2 (from apache-airflow==1.10.5)
  Using cached dill-0.2.9.tar.gz (150 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting dumb-init>=1.2.2 (from apache-airflow==1.10.5)
  Using cached dumb-init-1.2.5.post1.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting flask<2.0,>=1.1.0 (from apache-airflow==1.10.5)
  Using cached Flask-1.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5 (from apache-airflow==1.10.5)
  Using cached Flask-AppBuilder-1.13.1.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      <string>:3: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
      error in Flask-AppBuilder setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          apispec[yaml]>=1.1.1<2
                       ~~~~~~~^
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think pip version is the issue root cause, so try to downgrade it

`pip install pip==20.1.1`

Or if it's possible, upgrade airflow to at least 1.10.7 version, starting from it  the newest version of pip will work correctly.